# Bootstrap tab in modal popup is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I found a Bootstrap tab inside a modal popup(for login registration) in **Codepen**. The code is for only two tabs -Login & Registration- inside a modal popup. So, I added another tab for "Forgot Password".

But the problem is that `forgot password` tab isn't working at all, it isn't clickable at all. Nothing happens when I clicked on it.

### The Code

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Areas/Landing/Views/Shared/_LandingLayout.cshtml";
}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container mt-5 pt-5 modal" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="card mx-auto  border-0" style="width: 24rem;">
              <div class="card-header border-bottom-0 bg-transparent">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>

                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center pt-4" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active text-primary" id="pills-login-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-login" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-login"
                             aria-selected="true">Login</a>
                      </li>

                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link text-primary" id="pills-forgotpassword-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-forgotpassword" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-forgotpassword"
                             aria-selected="false">Forgot Password</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link text-primary" id="pills-register-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-register" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-register"
                             aria-selected="false">Register</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>

              </div>

              <div class="card-body pb-4">
                  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">

                      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-login-tab">
                          @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Landing/Views/Account/_Login.cshtml")
                          @*<div id="partialSummaryDiv"> Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Landing/Views/Account/_Login.cshtml", Model);</div>*@

                      </div>

                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-register" role="tabpanel" 
                           aria-labelledby="pills-register-tab">
                          @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Landing/Views/Account/_Register.cshtml")
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-forgotpassword" role="tabpanel" 
                           aria-labelledby="pills-forgotpassword-tab">
                          @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Landing/Views/Account/_Register.cshtml")
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry...My mistake.. I had a javascript for the modal popup as below. There was spelling error - I had typed "Forget Password" instead of "Forgot Password".

```
        $(() => {

            $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click((e) => {
                if (e.target.innerHTML !== "Login" && e.target.innerHTML !== "Register"
                    && e.target.innerHTML !== "Forgot Password")
                {
                const target = $(e.target.hash);

                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);

                    //debugger;
                    return false;
        }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Creating Dynamic Tabs in Bootstrap via Data attributes</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
                    <div class="card mx-auto  border-0" style="width: 24rem;">
                        <div class="card-header border-bottom-0 bg-transparent">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>

                             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#home" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">Login</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#profile" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Forgot Password</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#messages" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Register</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body pb-4">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">
                                    <h4 class="mt-2">Login</h4>
                                    <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                                    <h4 class="mt-2">Forgot Password</h4>
                                    <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
                                    <h4 class="mt-2">Register</h4>
                                    <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```